# How do I prevent color of circles from being updated?

Tags: javascript

I want to make 100 balls with different colors randomly moving on the canvas. Now, I've a problem, everytime I call the *this.update()* which  further calls *this.draw()*, it updates the *c.fillStyle* property too, which holds randomly generated colors.Hence, It keeps updating the color of the circles. 
Is there any way so that I could stop the *c.fillStyle* from being updated when caller is *this.update()*?

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;
function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.draw = function() {
        var i = 0
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        c.fill();
    }
    this.update = function() {


            if ((this.x + this.radius) >innerWidth || (this.x - this.radius) < 0) {
                this.dx = -this.dx;
            }
            this.x += this.dx;
            if ((this.y + this.radius) >innerHeight || (this.y - this.radius) < 0) {
                this.dy = -this.dy;
            }
            this.y += this.dy;
            this.draw();
        }    
}
var circles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var radius = 30;
    var x = Math.random() * (window.innerWidth-2*radius)+radius;
    var y = Math.random() * (window.innerHeight-2*radius)+radius;
    circles.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy,  radius));     
}
function animate() {
         requestAnimationFrame(animate);
         c.clearRect(0,0, innerWidth,innerHeight);            
         for(var i = 0; i< circles.length;i++)
              circles[i].update();
     }
     animate();
```

Comment: Pass a flag, if set, don't change. Also please click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply store the color, so that it will stay consistent:

```
     this.draw = function() {
       c.beginPath();
       c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
       c.fillStyle = this.color || ( this.color = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
       c.fill();
    }
```

Some explanations:

```
 this.color || (..
```

means that it should take `this.color` and if that does not exist it should evaluate the following part and take that:

```
 this.color = ...
```

so then the color is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Same response as Jonas W., but you can store the color outside the draw method (IMHO: it's cleaner):

```js
this.fillStyle = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
this.draw = function() {
    var i = 0
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
    c.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate colours before instantiating new circle and pass to the constructor the color calculated. IE:

```
new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius, color);
```